# Drag File Warning Extension VS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am wondering if anyone knows an extension that pops up a warning if you drag a file to another folder through VS 2010 solution explorer. Many times I will be on a file and my computer may lag for a second and all of a sudden the file is now in some other folder and I may not even notice it.

Comment: Can you please select shamp00's answer is correct and award him the bounty?  Otherwise, this question may be closed before and he'll lose the bounty award.

Comment: Hmmm.  Chobo2 - you didn't specify "free" as part of the criteria for the question - but perhaps you placed the bounty and said "free" after the non-free answer was posted?...  Whether or not you award the bounty, I will post a 100 rep bounty for someone to find a free extension - on a new question if you close this one.

Comment: No I posted the bounty before any possible answers were given(hence why I never edited my original question). I have no plans to close this question as I really would like to find this extension(that is free - not going to pay $50 for VSCommands for one feature and hence why I have not rewarded the bounty to shamp00 as even a paid option it is just way to much for one feature that I am asking for.)

Answer (score 7):

There is a Visual Studio extension available called [VSCommands 2010](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d491911d-97f3-4cf6-87b0-6a2882120acf/) which has a feature *Prevent accidental Drag & Drop in Solution Explorer*.

[image]

**Edit**
The feature is part of the Pro package which is not free.

Comment: It isn't free.  Shopping questions suck.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a free Visual Studio extension that would do it, but here is a C# sample of an Addin that demonstrate how to hook into Visual Studio global remove & rename file management. It's based on the [IVsTrackProjectDocumentsEvents2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb169648%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) interface.

You would have to extend the two OnQueryxxx methods to suit your needs.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using EnvDTE;
using EnvDTE80;
using Extensibility;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop;

namespace MyAddin1
{
    public class Connect : IDTExtensibility2, IVsTrackProjectDocumentsEvents2
    {
        private uint _trackerCookie;

        public void OnConnection(object application, ext_ConnectMode connectMode, object addInInst, ref Array custom)
        {
            _applicationObject = (DTE2)application;
            _addInInstance = (AddIn)addInInst;

            // the Addin project needs assembly references to Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop && Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop
            // any version should do
            ServiceProvider sp = new ServiceProvider((Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider)_applicationObject);
            IVsTrackProjectDocuments2 tracker = (IVsTrackProjectDocuments2)sp.GetService(typeof(SVsTrackProjectDocuments));

            // ask VS to notify us of files & directories changes
            tracker.AdviseTrackProjectDocumentsEvents(this, out _trackerCookie);
        }

        public void OnDisconnection(ext_DisconnectMode disconnectMode, ref Array custom)
        {
            if (_trackerCookie != 0)
            {
                // we quit, tell VS not to notify us anymore
                ServiceProvider sp = new ServiceProvider((Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider)_applicationObject);
                IVsTrackProjectDocuments2 tracker = (IVsTrackProjectDocuments2)sp.GetService(typeof(SVsTrackProjectDocuments));
                tracker.UnadviseTrackProjectDocumentsEvents(_trackerCookie);
                _trackerCookie = 0;
            }
        }

        public int OnQueryRenameFiles(IVsProject pProject, int cFiles, string[] rgszMkOldNames, string[] rgszMkNewNames, VSQUERYRENAMEFILEFLAGS[] rgFlags, VSQUERYRENAMEFILERESULTS[] pSummaryResult, VSQUERYRENAMEFILERESULTS[] rgResults)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("OnQueryRenameFiles pProject:" + pProject + " old[0]:" + rgszMkOldNames[0] + " new[0]:" + rgszMkNewNames[0]);

            // TODO: implement this (I have assumed cFiles is 1 here)
            if (!NotRenameOk(old[0], new[0])
            {
                rgResults[0] = VSQUERYRENAMEFILERESULTS.VSQUERYRENAMEFILERESULTS_RenameNotOK; // nope, it's not ok
            }
            return 0;
        }

        public int OnQueryRemoveFiles(IVsProject pProject, int cFiles, string[] rgpszMkDocuments, VSQUERYREMOVEFILEFLAGS[] rgFlags, VSQUERYREMOVEFILERESULTS[] pSummaryResult, VSQUERYREMOVEFILERESULTS[] rgResults)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("OnQueryRemoveFiles pProject:" + pProject + " file[0]:" + rgpszMkDocuments[0]);

            // TODO: needs to be implemented, use rgResults to tell VS if it's ok or not
            return 0;
        }

        // other IVsTrackProjectDocumentsEvents2 methods implementation omitted for brevity...
```

Comment: not ...entirely... sure how to begin to use this code.  Can you link me to any applicable sample projects / examples / resources to do with how to code vs2010 add ins?

Comment: @perfectionist - You can use Visual Studio to create such an addin: just choose New Project/Other Project Types/Extensibility and Visual Studio Add-in, then copy paste the code. However, if you don't have a developer at hand, you won't be able to implement the workings of OnQueryRename/Remove...

Comment: Okay, it looks like this might be feasible - you've certainly given me something to do about the problem, so you are hereby awarded the bounty.  Huzzah.  I'll post back to this question with results.